# How to compute percentage of correctly classified for a categorical variable in R?

Tags: r

I had applied mode imputation to replace the missing values contained in a categorical variable. The original values were included in variable A. As for imputed values it will be represented as variable B. The variable A consists values of 1 and 2 as follows:

```
A
1
2
1
1
2
```

The imputed values included in variable B are shown below.

```
B
2
2
2
2
2
```

The question is how can I compute the percentage of correctly classified values of the categorical variable as a measurement of error performance?

Comment: Start with 'table(A,B)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your (example) data:

```
A <- c(1,2,1,1,2)
B <- c(2,2,2,2,2)
```

If you want to see which `B`s were classified correctly, you can use

```
A == B
```

which is TRUE if B matches A, and FALSE otherwise.

Then for a percentage you could:

```
sum(A == B)/length(A)
```

, where `sum(A==B)` counts how many elements were correctly classified.

Or

```
mean(A == B)
```

is a cool way to say the same thing.

Comment: Thank you so much mathematical.coffee for helping me out.